# Version history(display form) shows only the latest version data

Tags: list, version-history, display-form

I've a custom list with version history enabled in SharePoint 2010.

When I open the version history data,all the versions shows only the latest version data.

Actually when I click on "Version history",the pop-up shows all the versions.Here the data for each version are displayed correctly. But when I open each version in a new tab, it displays only the latest version data.

Comment: Does anyone have a reply for this?

Comment: How do you open it in new tab? And is your purpose to open it in a new tab?

Comment: @AsadRefai To see all the column data,i open it in a new tab.. I right click on the version date and select "open in a new tab"

Comment: What URL do you see in new tab? Ideally `/Lists/test/DispForm.aspx?ID=4&VersionNo=512` this should be the format to see versions

Comment: @AsadRefai Yes exactly,this is the URL I see.I'm facing this issue in 2 lists and all other lists display the version history data as expected.

Comment: That's weird, you can compare between these lists if you have any differences in the settings.

Comment: @AsadRefai I compared the lists and there is no difference.But if i edit /Lists/test/DispForm.aspx?ID=4&VersionNo=512 page,I'm able to see a difference in the webpart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display form had been customized to display in a **Data Form webpart**,after I made it to display it in **List Form webpart**,the issue got resolved.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? I'm facing the same issue and gave your suggestion a try. I changed <WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart> to <WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart> (the closing tags as well) and got a web part error like "An object of type System.Int32 can not be created by its string representation {@ID} on the ItemId property." (sorry, google translate gave me this). Did I miss something?

Comment: @airliner edit the page using SPDesigner and add the form again

Comment: George, you may help me a bit further. (Or I am too confused about this) My originated custom form was created via SPDesigner (as descriped here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/create-new-custom-display-form-list-using-sharepoint-designe/). But this leads me to another DataFormWebPart as default which I don't want to have. A ListFormWebPart looks quite different (and is only receiveable copying the default display form) and is not customizable via SPDesigner, right?
What do I miss here? So far I didn't find a goot source for custom forms with ability of history/versioning...