# DispForm does not show prior version

Tags: version-history, display-form, list-form-web-part

*My question is the same as [Version history(display form) shows only the latest version data](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153408/version-historydisplay-form-shows-only-the-latest-version-data), except that the accepted answer in that question does not solve my problem. More details below the question.*

---

I have a custom list, with major versioning enabled, in SharePoint 2010. When I choose "Version History" on a list item, I get the normal dialog box listing the previous versions, and the new values of each column that changed from the prior version - this part is fine.

But when I click on any of the prior versions in that dialog, to attempt to view that prior version in its entirety, then even though the URL I get is what it should be - `/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?ID=77&VersionNo=1024` - I am actually presented with the contents of the current version of the item, and not the actual prior version as I should be getting. This happens regardless of whether I attempt to open the prior version by clicking directly on the timestamp (which opens the DispForm.aspx in a new tab), or by clicking on View under the dropdown menu for the item (which opens in the same dialog that had been displaying the version list). Now, if from this page I click Site Settings > Edit Page (only accessible from the non-dialog approach), I find myself in edit mode for a web part page for the DispForm.aspx, but *now* the prior version I was attempting to view is actually displayed.

Why am I seeing this, and how can I fix it?

I do have access to SharePoint Designer if necessary, but this is happening on OOTB forms that have not been customized in Designer. I do not have access to PowerShell or to the server; I am a Site Collection Administrator for the affected site collection.

---

The answer in the other question I linked above (to change the DispForm.aspx from using a Data Form Web Part to using a List Form Web Part) is not a solution for me, because my DispForm.aspx is *already* using a LFWP. (Another difference in my situation is that where the other question's asker was only seeing the issue on two lists in his site, I am seeing it on every list in my site collection, but not in any other site collections.

One additional detail that may or may not be relevant: while each previous version that I attempt to view displays all of the column values as they are in the current version of the list item, at the very bottom of the form, there is one difference between attempting to view a previous version and viewing the current version:

**Viewing actual current version:**
<sub>Content Type: Item

Version: 12.0

Created at 10/13/2014 11:18 AM by **

Last modified at 9/2/2015 7:54 AM by **</sub>

**Attempting to view any previous version:**
<sub>Content Type: Item

Version: 12.0

Created at 9/2/2015 7:54 AM by **</sub>

Where 9/2/2015 is in fact the timestamp of version 12.0.